# Can't access Google AppEngine external libraries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cygwin, environment-variables

Please help... I am running some python code from cygwin and I can't import the GoogleAppEngine (GAE) External Data API.  I think this may be an environment variable problem.  I am able to run GAE and the 'remote_data_api_shell.py' from the command line, but I cannot run a python module that references GAE.

I'm in trial-and-error mode trying every combination of environment variable strings I can think of.  Nothing works and my frustration is mounting.

1. GAE(1.5) is located in (windows path):  C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine
2. Here is my Python Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/cygdrive/c/data/my-program/MyProgram.py", line 48, in '<'module'>'
>
> > from Model import MyStoredObject
> >      File "/cygdrive/c/data/my-program/Model.py", line 6, in '<'module'>'
> >        from google.appengine.ext import db
> >     ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext

1. I setup my environment variables in my cygwin bashrc file.  My bashrc file contains

   > GAE_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Google/google_appengine"
   >
   > I tried many combinations of strings and characters here.
   >
   > PATH="$PATH:$GAE_HOME
   >
   > PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$GAE_HOME:$GAE_HOME/lib/yaml/lib:
   >
   > Also tried `$GAE_HOME/google/appengine/ext` and many more...
   >
   > export PYTHONPATH
   >
   > export PATH
   >
   > export GAE_HOME

How can I make this work?  Anything obvious to a GAE expert that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have this at the top of scripts I run that need to interact with the appengine SDK

```
import sys
import os

# locate app-engine SDK
AE_PATH = "/path/to/sdk/google_appengine/"

# path to app code
APP_PATH = os.path.abspath(".")

# load the AE paths (as stolen from dev_appserver.py)
EXTRA_PATHS = [
    APP_PATH,
    AE_PATH,
    os.path.join(AE_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3'),
    os.path.join(AE_PATH, 'lib', 'django'),
    os.path.join(AE_PATH, 'lib', 'ipaddr'),
    os.path.join(AE_PATH, 'lib', 'webob'),
    os.path.join(AE_PATH, 'lib', 'yaml', 'lib'),
    os.path.join(AE_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'), # issue[1]
]
sys.path = EXTRA_PATHS + sys.path
```

[1] [fancy_urllib issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=178)

Hopefully that points you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks...That worked!!!  Also I moved GAE out of the default windows Program Files directory.  It helped for simplicity not having spaces and '(' characters in my $GAE_PATH.

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the paths:

```
sdk_path = "/path/to/sdk/google_appengine/"
sys.path.insert(0, sdk_path)
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```